Remote desktop into RPi with XRDP, immediately exiting upon successful login
I am running the latest version of XRDP, and RPi software.
Some of the things I have tried: -logging in with another user (same issue) -logging out of all accounts and trying to login via remote desktop -rebooting the RPi
Here is my XRDP.log file for a particular connection attempt:
[20240315-09:06:23] [INFO ] xrdp_load_keyboard_layout: Keyboard information sent by the RDP client, keyboard_type:[0x07], keyboard_subtype:[0x00], keylayout:[0x00000409]
[20240315-09:06:23] [INFO ] xrdp_load_keyboard_layout: model [] variant [] layout [us] options []
[20240315-09:06:23] [INFO ] Non-TLS connection established from ::ffff:myip port 51888: with security level : high
[20240315-09:06:23] [INFO ] xrdp_caps_process_pointer: client supports new(color) cursor
[20240315-09:06:23] [INFO ] xrdp_process_offscreen_bmpcache: support level 1 cache size 10485760 MB cache entries 100
[20240315-09:06:23] [INFO ] xrdp_caps_process_codecs: nscodec, codec id 1, properties len 3
[20240315-09:06:23] [WARN ] xrdp_caps_process_codecs: unknown codec id 5
[20240315-09:06:23] [INFO ] xrdp_caps_process_codecs: RemoteFX, codec id 3, properties len 49
[20240315-09:06:23] [INFO ] Loading keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-00000409.ini
[20240315-09:06:23] [WARN ] local keymap file for 0x00000409 found and doesn't match built in keymap, using local keymap file
[20240315-09:08:31] [INFO ] connecting to sesman on myip:3350
[20240315-09:08:31] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sesman connect ok
[20240315-09:08:31] [INFO ] sesman connect ok
[20240315-09:08:31] [INFO ] sending login info to session manager. Please wait...
[20240315-09:08:31] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: login successful for user llopez46 on display 10
[20240315-09:08:31] [INFO ] login successful for user llopez46 on display 10
[20240315-09:08:31] [INFO ] loaded module 'libxup.so' ok, interface size 10296, version 4
[20240315-09:08:31] [INFO ] started connecting
[20240315-09:08:31] [INFO ] lib_mod_connect: connecting via UNIX socket
[20240315-09:08:31] [INFO ] lib_mod_log_peer: xrdp_pid=4259 connected to X11rdp_pid=4769 X11rdp_uid=1000 X11rdp_gid=1000 client_ip=::ffff:myip client_port=51888
[20240315-09:08:31] [INFO ] connected ok

This is my system Journal for a login attempt
'''
Mar 20 08:02:40 raspberrypi xrdp[824]: [INFO ] Socket 12: AF_INET6 connection received from ::ffff:myip port 50693
Mar 20 08:02:40 raspberrypi xrdp[1942]: [INFO ] Using default X.509 certificate: /etc/xrdp/cert.pem
Mar 20 08:02:40 raspberrypi xrdp[1942]: [INFO ] Using default X.509 key file: /etc/xrdp/key.pem
Mar 20 08:02:40 raspberrypi xrdp[1942]: [ERROR] Cannot read private key file /etc/xrdp/key.pem: Permission denied
Mar 20 08:02:40 raspberrypi xrdp[1942]: [WARN ] Cannot accept TLS connections because certificate or private key file is not readable. certificate file: [/etc/xrdp/cert.pem], private key file: [/etc/xrdp/key.pem]
Mar 20 08:02:40 raspberrypi xrdp[1942]: [INFO ] Security protocol: configured [RDP], requested [SSL|HYBRID|HYBRID_EX|RDP], selected [RDP]
Mar 20 08:02:40 raspberrypi xrdp[1942]: [ERROR] libxrdp_force_read: header read error
Mar 20 08:02:40 raspberrypi xrdp[1942]: [ERROR] Processing [ITU-T T.125] Connect-Initial failed
Mar 20 08:02:40 raspberrypi xrdp[1942]: [ERROR] [MCS Connection Sequence] receive connection request failed
Mar 20 08:02:40 raspberrypi xrdp[1942]: [ERROR] xrdp_sec_incoming: xrdp_mcs_incoming failed
Mar 20 08:02:40 raspberrypi xrdp[1942]: [ERROR] xrdp_rdp_incoming: xrdp_sec_incoming failed
Mar 20 08:02:40 raspberrypi xrdp[1942]: [ERROR] xrdp_process_main_loop: libxrdp_process_incoming failed
Mar 20 08:02:40 raspberrypi xrdp[824]: [INFO ] Socket 12: AF_INET6 connection received from ::ffff:myip port 50694
Mar 20 08:02:40 raspberrypi xrdp[1942]: [ERROR] xrdp_iso_send: trans_write_copy_s failed
Mar 20 08:02:40 raspberrypi xrdp[1943]: [INFO ] Using default X.509 certificate: /etc/xrdp/cert.pem
Mar 20 08:02:40 raspberrypi xrdp[1942]: [ERROR] Sending [ITU T.125] DisconnectProviderUltimatum failed
Mar 20 08:02:40 raspberrypi xrdp[1943]: [INFO ] Using default X.509 key file: /etc/xrdp/key.pem
Mar 20 08:02:40 raspberrypi xrdp[1943]: [ERROR] Cannot read private key file /etc/xrdp/key.pem: Permission denied
Mar 20 08:02:40 raspberrypi xrdp[1943]: [WARN ] Cannot accept TLS connections because certificate or private key file is not readable. certificate file: [/etc/xrdp/cert.pem], private key file: [/etc/xrdp/key.pem]
Mar 20 08:02:40 raspberrypi xrdp[1943]: [INFO ] Security protocol: configured [RDP], requested [RDP], selected [RDP]
Mar 20 08:02:40 raspberrypi xrdp[1943]: [INFO ] Connected client computer name: A6445033
Mar 20 08:02:40 raspberrypi xrdp[1943]: [WARN ] Received [MS-RDPBCGR] TS_UD_HEADER type 0xc006 is unknown (ignored)
Mar 20 08:02:40 raspberrypi xrdp[1943]: [WARN ] Received [MS-RDPBCGR] TS_UD_HEADER type 0xc00a is unknown (ignored)
Mar 20 08:02:40 raspberrypi xrdp[1943]: [INFO ] xrdp_load_keyboard_layout: Keyboard information sent by the RDP client, keyboard_type:[0x07], keyboard_subtype:[0x00], keylayout:[0x00000409]
Mar 20 08:02:40 raspberrypi xrdp[1943]: [INFO ] xrdp_load_keyboard_layout: model [] variant [] layout [us] options []
Mar 20 08:02:40 raspberrypi xrdp[1943]: [INFO ] Non-TLS connection established from ::ffff:myip port 50694: with security level : high
Mar 20 08:02:40 raspberrypi xrdp[1943]: [INFO ] xrdp_caps_process_pointer: client supports new(color) cursor
Mar 20 08:02:40 raspberrypi xrdp[1943]: [INFO ] xrdp_process_offscreen_bmpcache: support level 1 cache size 10485760 MB cache entries 100
Mar 20 08:02:40 raspberrypi xrdp[1943]: [INFO ] xrdp_caps_process_codecs: nscodec, codec id 1, properties len 3
Mar 20 08:02:40 raspberrypi xrdp[1943]: [WARN ] xrdp_caps_process_codecs: unknown codec id 5
Mar 20 08:02:40 raspberrypi xrdp[1943]: [INFO ] xrdp_caps_process_codecs: RemoteFX, codec id 3, properties len 49
Mar 20 08:02:40 raspberrypi xrdp[1943]: [INFO ] Loading keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-00000409.ini
Mar 20 08:02:40 raspberrypi xrdp[1943]: [WARN ] local keymap file for 0x00000409 found and doesn't match built in keymap, using local keymap file
Mar 20 08:02:48 raspberrypi systemd-timesyncd[467]: Timed out waiting for reply from ipaddr:123 (2.debian.pool.ntp.org).
Mar 20 08:02:58 raspberrypi systemd-timesyncd[467]: Timed out waiting for reply from ipaddr:123 (2.debian.pool.ntp.org).
Mar 20 08:03:08 raspberrypi systemd-timesyncd[467]: Timed out waiting for reply from ipaddr:123 (2.debian.pool.ntp.org).
Mar 20 08:03:17 raspberrypi xrdp[1943]: [INFO ] connecting to sesman on 127.0.0.1:3350
Mar 20 08:03:17 raspberrypi xrdp-sesman[807]: [INFO ] Socket 12: AF_INET6 connection received from ::1 port 36308
Mar 20 08:03:18 raspberrypi xrdp[1943]: [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sesman connect ok
Mar 20 08:03:18 raspberrypi xrdp[1943]: [INFO ] sesman connect ok
Mar 20 08:03:18 raspberrypi xrdp[1943]: [INFO ] sending login info to session manager. Please wait...
Mar 20 08:03:18 raspberrypi xrdp-sesman[807]: [INFO ] Terminal Server Users group is disabled, allowing authentication
Mar 20 08:03:18 raspberrypi xrdp-sesman[807]: [INFO ] ++ created session (access granted): username llopez46, ip ::ffff:myip:50694 - socket: 12
Mar 20 08:03:18 raspberrypi xrdp-sesman[807]: [INFO ] starting Xorg session...
Mar 20 08:03:18 raspberrypi xrdp-sesman[807]: [INFO ] Starting session: session_pid 1945, display :10.0, width 1920, height 1080, bpp 24, client ip ::ffff:myip:50694 - socket: 12, user name llopez46
Mar 20 08:03:18 raspberrypi xrdp-sesman[1945]: [INFO ] [session start] (display 10): calling auth_start_session from pid 1945
Mar 20 08:03:18 raspberrypi xrdp-sesman[807]: [ERROR] sesman_data_in: scp_process_msg failed
Mar 20 08:03:18 raspberrypi xrdp[1943]: [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: login successful for user llopez46 on display 10
Mar 20 08:03:18 raspberrypi xrdp-sesman[1945]: pam_unix(xrdp-sesman:session): session opened for user llopez46(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Mar 20 08:03:18 raspberrypi xrdp[1943]: [INFO ] login successful for user llopez46 on display 10
Mar 20 08:03:18 raspberrypi systemd-logind[579]: New session c1 of user llopez46.
Mar 20 08:03:18 raspberrypi xrdp-sesman[807]: [ERROR] sesman_main_loop: trans_check_wait_objs failed, removing trans
Mar 20 08:03:18 raspberrypi xrdp[1943]: [INFO ] loaded module 'libxup.so' ok, interface size 10296, version 4
Mar 20 08:03:18 raspberrypi xrdp[1943]: [INFO ] started connecting
Mar 20 08:03:18 raspberrypi xrdp[1943]: [INFO ] lib_mod_connect: connecting via UNIX socket
Mar 20 08:03:18 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started session-c1.scope - Session c1 of User llopez46.
Mar 20 08:03:18 raspberrypi xrdp-sesman[1947]: [INFO ] Starting X server on display 10: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg :10 -auth .Xauthority -config xrdp/xorg.conf -noreset -nolisten tcp -logfile .xorgxrdp.%s.log
Mar 20 08:03:18 raspberrypi xrdp-sesman[1946]: [INFO ] Found X server running at /tmp/.X11-unix/X10
Mar 20 08:03:18 raspberrypi xrdp-sesman[1945]: [INFO ] Found X server running at /tmp/.X11-unix/X10
Mar 20 08:03:18 raspberrypi xrdp-sesman[1946]: [INFO ] Found X server running at /tmp/.X11-unix/X10
Mar 20 08:03:18 raspberrypi xrdp-sesman[1945]: [INFO ] Session started successfully for user llopez46 on display 10
Mar 20 08:03:18 raspberrypi xrdp-sesman[1951]: [INFO ] Starting the xrdp channel server for display 10
Mar 20 08:03:18 raspberrypi xrdp-sesman[1946]: [INFO ] Starting the default window manager on display 10: /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh
Mar 20 08:03:18 raspberrypi xrdp-sesman[1945]: [INFO ] Session in progress on display 10, waiting until the window manager (pid 1946) exits to end the session
Mar 20 08:03:18 raspberrypi xrdp[1943]: [INFO ] lib_mod_log_peer: xrdp_pid=1943 connected to X11rdp_pid=1947 X11rdp_uid=1000 X11rdp_gid=1000 client_ip=::ffff:myip client_port=50694
Mar 20 08:03:18 raspberrypi xrdp[1943]: [INFO ] connected ok
Mar 20 08:03:18 raspberrypi xrdp-chansrv[1951]: [INFO ] Socket 12: AF_UNIX connection received
Mar 20 08:03:18 raspberrypi systemd-timesyncd[467]: Timed out waiting for reply from ipaddr:123 (2.debian.pool.ntp.org).
Mar 20 08:03:19 raspberrypi dbus-daemon[946]: [session uid=1000 pid=946] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.Metadata' unit='gvfs-metadata.service' requested by ':1.11' (uid=1000 pid=1154 comm="pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi")
Mar 20 08:03:19 raspberrypi systemd[913]: Starting gvfs-metadata.service - Virtual filesystem metadata service...
Mar 20 08:03:19 raspberrypi dbus-daemon[946]: [session uid=1000 pid=946] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.Metadata'
Mar 20 08:03:19 raspberrypi systemd[913]: Started gvfs-metadata.service - Virtual filesystem metadata service.
Mar 20 08:03:19 raspberrypi xrdp-chansrv[1951]: [INFO ] sound_process_training: round trip time 100
Mar 20 08:03:19 raspberrypi xrdp-chansrv[1951]: [INFO ] Detected remote printer 'PRN6' (not supported)
Mar 20 08:03:19 raspberrypi xrdp-chansrv[1951]: [INFO ] Detected remote printer 'PRN7' (not supported)
Mar 20 08:03:19 raspberrypi xrdp-chansrv[1951]: [INFO ] Detected remote printer 'PRN5' (not supported)
Mar 20 08:03:19 raspberrypi xrdp-chansrv[1951]: [INFO ] Detected remote printer 'PRN4' (not supported)
Mar 20 08:03:19 raspberrypi xrdp-chansrv[1951]: [INFO ] Detected remote printer 'PRN3' (not supported)
Mar 20 08:03:19 raspberrypi xrdp-chansrv[1951]: [INFO ] Detected remote printer 'PRN2' (not supported)
Mar 20 08:03:19 raspberrypi xrdp-chansrv[1951]: [INFO ] Detected remote printer 'PRN1' (not supported)
Mar 20 08:03:19 raspberrypi xrdp-chansrv[1951]: [INFO ] Detected remote smartcard 'SCARD'
Mar 20 08:03:19 raspberrypi xrdp-sesman[1945]: [WARN ] Window manager (pid 1946, display 10) exited with non-zero exit code 1 and signal 0. This could indicate a window manager config problem
Mar 20 08:03:19 raspberrypi xrdp-sesman[1945]: [WARN ] Window manager (pid 1946, display 10) exited quickly (1 secs). This could indicate a window manager config problem
Mar 20 08:03:19 raspberrypi xrdp-sesman[1945]: [INFO ] Calling auth_stop_session and auth_end from pid 1945
Mar 20 08:03:19 raspberrypi xrdp-sesman[1945]: pam_unix(xrdp-sesman:session): session closed for user llopez46
Mar 20 08:03:19 raspberrypi xrdp-sesman[1945]: [INFO ] Terminating X server (pid 1947) on display 10
Mar 20 08:03:19 raspberrypi xrdp-sesman[1945]: [INFO ] Terminating the xrdp channel server (pid 1951) on display 10
Mar 20 08:03:19 raspberrypi systemd[1]: home-llopez46-thinclient_drives.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Mar 20 08:03:19 raspberrypi systemd-logind[579]: Failed to restore VT, ignoring: Bad file descriptor
Mar 20 08:03:20 raspberrypi xrdp-sesman[1945]: [INFO ] X server on display 10 (pid 1947) returned exit code 0 and signal number 0
Mar 20 08:03:20 raspberrypi xrdp-sesman[1945]: [INFO ] xrdp channel server for display 10 (pid 1951) exit code 0 and signal number 0
Mar 20 08:03:20 raspberrypi xrdp-sesman[1945]: [INFO ] cleanup_sockets:
Mar 20 08:03:20 raspberrypi xrdp-sesman[807]: [INFO ] Process 1945 has exited
Mar 20 08:03:20 raspberrypi systemd-logind[579]: Session c1 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Mar 20 08:03:20 raspberrypi xrdp-sesman[807]: [INFO ] ++ terminated session:  username llopez46, display :10.0, session_pid 1945, ip ::ffff:myip:50694 - socket: 12
Mar 20 08:03:29 raspberrypi systemd-timesyncd[467]: Timed out waiting for reply from myip:123 (3.debian.pool.ntp.org).
Mar 20 08:03:29 raspberrypi systemd[1]: session-c1.scope: Deactivated successfully.
Mar 20 08:03:29 raspberrypi systemd-logind[579]: Removed session c1.
'''

The log you provided was too old, anyway can you show the system journal?
